# Is there a way to move between cards without buttons in LiveCode?

Tags: livecode

I have 4 cards in a mainstack in livecode , each card with a next and back buttons that take you to the next or previous card .Is there a script or a way to  define the program so that the transition to the next card   will happen without the button next   and without any button at all ? 
 I wrote this script in the stack script 
is this right ?
[image: code script]

Comment: Your code works. When you click anywhere on the card, it starts moving to the next card every two seconds. It will continue infinitely until you click anywhere on the card again. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No buttons are needed to initiate this, since the `mouseUp` handlers are in the stack script.

Comment: ok thank you , That is what i wanted , but i was not sure , thanks Devin

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply trying to initiate the navigation from a script or some other event, you should be able to script any of these:

```
go next card
go prev card
go card 4
go first card
go last card
```

If that's not what you're looking for, please describe your situation in more detail.

Comment: I added the code i wrote , but when i try it it keeps switching to cards like crazy and it won't let me  press any buttons either while doing that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the navigationArrows property. If this property is true the user will be able to navigate between the cards using his keyboard.

```
set the navigationArrows to true
```